# How to fix error 403 from geodataclient on a debug.apk tested on a device that has not being installed directly form android studio?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm working on an app that uses the GeoDataClient of google API for android to get a place with by id. The problem is that whenever I run the app directly from the android studio I get results, but when I build a debug.apk for testing and install it manually (without an android studio) in other devices, the geoDataApi throws an exception that refuses to connect or returns 403 error.

I've already set up my sha1 certificate fingerprint for debugging, and also tried with a different API key without a fingerprint, but still the same issue. Also, the apikey is enabled for billing. I'm using GeoDataClient because of this [Link](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/googleapi-migration)

**Heres the manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <permission
        android:name="my.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="my.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Here's the request for geoDataClient.getPlaceByid:**

```
        geoDataClient.getPlaceById(place.getPlaceId()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlaceBufferResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlaceBufferResponse> task) {
                    try{
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            PlaceBufferResponse places = task.getResult();
                            com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place myPlace = places.get(0);
                            Log.i("PLACE", "Place found: " + myPlace.getLatLng());

                            places.release();
                        } else {
                            Log.e("PLACE", "Place not found.");
                        }
                    }catch (RuntimeException r){
                        Log.e("PLACES EXCEPTION", ""+r);
                    }

                }
            });
```

EDIT:

Yesterday I also set an sha1 certificate for release to the api key and tried testing with a release apk but the map is blank when trying the app.